# PHP session_regenerate_id (true) Not working as it should

Tags: php, sql, session, pdo

EDIT: 4
I went and tried this out with teh regular session handler, same issue could it be some OS error?

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['h0']=5;
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

> Again when reloading the page multiple times you get A LOT sessions all with the same data.

For some reason when executing this script the

```
define('endl', "<br>");
$session->start_session();
echo session_id().endl;
session_regenerate_id(true);
echo session_id().endl;
```

> On the top part I'm  using delete_old_session
>
> session_regenerate_id(true)
>
> bool session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )
>
> So the expected behavior is to generate a new session and then delete the old one

if I execute it normally I have the right behavior...

output:

```
d5ips18ji4rg7q63skuf7955b4
udk903d5o2nbeoq5soujng0bp5
```

---

http://s7.postimg.org/67dbyv3x7/image.png

---

But if I reload the page multiple times, (keep f5 pressed for a couple o seconds...)
it created over 60 sessions

---

http://s7.postimg.org/442wr744b/image.png

I dont know if Im implementing this correctly...

EDIT 2: 
Destroy callback

```
public function destroy($sessionId) {
    $qry = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id";
    if (!isset($this->dStatement)) {
        $this->dStatement = $this->pdo->prepare($qry);
    }
    $this->dStatement->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($this->dStatement->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "error destroy()";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've even tryied this methods insted of the regular sess_reg_id(true)

```
public function regen_id(){
    $sessionId = session_id();
    echo $sessionId;
    $qry = "INSERT INTO sessiondeletequeue VALUES (:id, 0)";
    if(!isset($this->regQuery)){
        $this->regQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($qry);
    }
    $this->regQuery->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($this->regQuery->execute()){
        session_regenerate_id();
        echo "<br>";
        $this->forceDelete();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
private function forceDelete(){
    $qry = "SELECT id FROM sessiondeletequeue";
    foreach($this->pdo->query($qry) as $row){
        $this->destroy($row['id']);
        if(!isset($this->forceQuery)){
            $this->forceQuery = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE sessiondeletequeue SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = :id");
        }
        $this->forceQuery->bindParam(':id', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $this->forceQuery->execute();
    }
    $this->pdo->query("DELETE FROM sessiondeletequeue WHERE deleted = 1 ");
```

***EDIT 3:
I know I could find a way around it, but I'm curious to know why the heck is creating that many sessions!! D:***

Comment: bool session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )
delete_old_session
Whether to delete the old associated session file or not.

Comment: Could be a flaw in your implementation of the `destroy` callback?

Comment: I;ve edited the post and added the destroy   to it

Comment: -1 for mixing incomparable matters. PDO has nothing to do with sessions. You have to debug them separately

Comment: @YourCommonSense Could you be more specific? im not debugging PDO I know for sure that those queries work as they should... I'm not even using the last 2 methods, I wrote them just to "try" to get the desired behavior but its the same result, so I would appreciate the help on my real issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably mixing up PHP's default session mechanism with your framework's or your own session implementation.

```
$session->start_session(); // where does $session come from?
//and then
session_id();
```

Yes, it's working the expected way. You're generating a new session ID on every page reload. So the newly generated session ID is being stored on the database.

Regenerate the session ID only when you need. You probably don't need it generated on every request to the page.

Comment: As he points out, providing `true` as the arg to session_regenerate_id is supposed to delete the old session.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Thanks for pointing out. Yes, looks like he's using both $session and session_* functions. Edited my answers.

Comment: But still if I were mixing shouldnt the $_SESSION go to temp and my $session to DB ? still the same thing right? 
shouldnt  session_set_save_handler override the way PHP handles sessions?  heres part of my session class http://pastebin.com/iZ2qt37V